# Use browser for authentication from console app, similar to authentication by az login

Tags: authentication, browser-automation

I would like automate some tasks and use e.g. console app or Excel to retrieve data from a web application's API.

My web application uses corporate SSO with redirects to IdM (it uses authorization code flow). Currently I work like this - I open the web app, authenticate and when the client receives the access token I take it (steal it from the API request's Authorization header) and then use it in Excel to call a specific API to get the data that I need.

It is quite annoying, I need to do it whenever the token expires. I would like to be able to initiate the authentication from the other app (excel, console, ..).

I like the way how e.g. az cli does the authentication (`az login`) - it opens browser, user authenticates and then it grabs the credentials somehow from the browser. There is a redirect to localhost so I suppose the cli listens on a specific port on localhost.

I would like to learn more on this, how could I easily imitate this behavior?